# Does rabbitmq have operations log?

Tags: logging, redis, rabbitmq, message-queue, task-queue

I need to see what operations are happening inside rabbitmq similar to `redis-cli monitor` or redis aof. Does rabbitmq have this capability?

Answer (score 1):

Messages can be traced with [Firehose Tracer](https://www.rabbitmq.com/firehose.html).

Various events (such as queues, exchanges, connections, vhosts, users, etc. being created or deleted) can be consumed with the [Event Exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/event-exchange.html) plugin.